# python beautifulsoup get html tag content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get the content of an html tag with beautifulsoup? for example the content of `<title>` tag?

I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='http://www.websiteaddress.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
result = soup.findAll('title')
for each in result:
    print(each.get_text())
```

But nothing happened. I'm using python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch the website data first. You can do this with the `urllib.request` module. Note that HTML documents only have one title so there is no need to use `find_all()` and a loop.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='http://www.websiteaddress.com'
data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('title')
print(result.get_text())
```

Comment: @niloofar Glad I could help!